# TCXO specification ambiguity

Tags: oscillator, maximum-ratings, specifications, tcxo

I am going through datasheet of `TXKTPCSANF-32.000000`. I require a clipped sine-wave TCXO with 1.8 Vpp maximum. However, the [datasheet](http://www.taitien.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/XO-0076_TX.pdf) of the TCXO doesn't state the maximum Vpp. They have mentioned 0.8Vpp as minimum.

Find the screenshot of the datesheet below:

[image]

Am I missing something? Is there any standard to calculate max vpp of the TCXO? Or I assume it is the Vdd supplied to the TCXO?

**EDIT:**

We have part with 3.3V in stock. I am not sure if I can use the part with RF Front-end (`SX1257`). Is it possible that 3.3V variant of the TCXO may output less than 1.8 Vpp?

Comment: It shouldn't ever go above the supply voltage. If your 1.8V is a maximum, just give the thing 1.8V and it'll give you less than 1.8V out.

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify my issue in detail.

Comment: If you have stock, why not test it? then use a  C voltage divider if necessary 10pF>20pF

Comment: I can test it but still want to be sure if this TCXO can exceed 1.8V. May be in the conditions I will check it (like temperature), it behaves properly but can do something nasty in other conditions?

Comment: To avoid overshoots, insert a 100 Ohm resistor ---- in series with the output pin. Read up on "source termination".

Comment: Then I need to have 100 ohm transmission line?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Do I need 100 ohm transmission line? I have read that sum of source termination impedance and output impedance of source should be equal to characteristic impedance of line. Am I correct?